# Set a datasource with a SQL Server database in a Java project?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, servlets, datasource

I have Java project and a SQL Server database. I would like to connect my project to my database so that when I build the project's war file it can already connect to my database when I load it on a server (Tomcat by example). For that, I tried to use datasource as it is defined in this tutorial : [how to define  datasource jndi in java with tomcat](https://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java)
but the connection to my database does not get success. Here is how I modified the files in tomcat:

In the conf/context.xml

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>"
                global="jdbc/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

In the server.xml file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>" 
  global="jdbc/<MY_DATABASE_NAME>" 
  auth="Container" 
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
  url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=<MY_DATABASE_NAME>" 
  username=USERNAME
  password=PASSWORD/>
```

Although this configuration, I cannot connect to my database

Update: tcp/ip is enabled and it is running on port 1433,
the error i got from the connection is

> No Appropriate protocol(protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71366799/edit) your question to contain more information. When you say you cannot connect to your database - what's the error message you get (as text)? What version and edition of SQL Server do you have installed? Is the TCP/IP protocol enabled (check this in SQL Server [version] Configuration Manager)? What TCP/IP port is it configured to listen on (it may not be port 1433)?

Comment: i update my question @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Suspect this is a TLS encryption issue. As a first pass you could temporarily confirm whether or not this is the case by adding `;encrypt=false` to your URL/connection string. If that allows the connection then probably your JRE requires TLS 1.2 connections and your target SQL Server is an older release that only supports TLS 1.0 and/or TLS 1.1 connectivity.

Comment: i got the same error when i add this option encrypt=false